# Is it possible to connect a ML code made in python with a Wix template?

Tags: python, velo

I have a Python app that I need to integrate with a Wix website. The objective is to collect inputs from Wix into the Python code and display the Python outputs, such as Matplotlib visualizations, on the Wix site. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably not directly like that but you can develop an API with `FastAPI` and use javascript to consume your remote API.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.